# Обновление списка новостей

Tags: php, html, sql

Может тема покажется глупой, однако, как называется система, которая обновляет содержимое страницы новостей, к примеру, с 1 на 2 страницу?
Пример:

[image: Смысал?]

Гуглил, но не мог найти и близко что-то подобное.
Если возможно, подкиньте ссылку, где объясняется, как такое сделать.

Comment: _система_ такая называется постраничным выводом элементов, или пагинацией (pagination). Вам нужно 1) знать сколько всего новостей 2) знать номер запрашиваемой страницы 3) знать число новостей на страницу 4) написать запрос выборки данных из БД. в mysql, к примеру, это обычно достигается кодом вида `.... LIMIT x, y` где `х` принимает значение `(pageNum - 1)*pageSize` а `y` - `pageSize`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пагинация это называется. Возможно эти материалы вам помогут:

[Простая пагинация на php](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/25926/)

[Как разбить вывод из mysql постранично](http://phpfaq.ru/mysql/paginator)